# Interacting CFT fixed point of an RG flow

Tags: renormalization, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance

Suppose we have a gauge theory defined in the UV and it flows to an interacting CFT in the IR, i.e. the beta function vanishes for some finite value of the coupling. I am confused about the meaning of this. Isn't a CFT by definition scale independent? But we have the CFT only at a particular energy scale where the beta function vanishes. So what do we mean when we say that at some energy scale the theory does not depend on the energy scale?

Comment: Different points along the flow are different models, related to each other by an overall change of scale. Flowing all the way to the IR means taking the energy-momentum scale-factor all the way to zero. You seem to be trying to compare energies in the CFT to energies at some other point along the flow. Is that a good interpretation of the question?

Comment: Or maybe this: In a scale-invariant model, all of the beta-functions are zero, but maybe a model that is not scale-invariant could also have a zero beta-function. Are you asking if that's possible?

Comment: Yes, what you said in the first comment. But I'm still confused. They are different models but they describe the same system at different energies, right? So I don't understand what is the meaning of having the CFT at a specific point in the RG trajectory. What happens if we change the energy in the CFT will we move to another point in the RG ? seems I have a distorted picture of the meaning of renormalization group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion arises from the following fact:

In the situation that you describe, the beta function vanishes at some finite value of the **coupling**. But it does *not* vanish at a finite value of the **energy**!

When you go down in energy from the UV to the IR, the coupling increases from zero to its fixed point value. But it never exactly reaches the fixed-point value. The closer you get to the fixed point, the slower the coupling runs with energy (that's the definition of a beta function approaching zero). You only get to the IR interacting CFT in the strict limit of zero energy.

As you correctly pointed out, you can never have a CFT at a given energy scale. A CFT is by definition scale-free.

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks!!